# SmtpClient throws IOException

Tags: c#, smtpclient

It seems that SmtpClient throw an IOException on disposing.
The Mail were sent sucessfully with no error.
The Exeption were catched by the second catch block in the code,
after the Smtp Client should be disposed.
The Mail was sent sucessfully

```
public static async Task<String> SendMail(MailMessage mailMessage)
    {
        String errorString = "";
        try
        {
            using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(SMTPServer, SMTPPort))
            {

                smtpClient.EnableSsl = StartTLS;
                if (SMTPAuthenticationRequired)
                {
                    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(SMTPUsername, SMTPPassword);
                    smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
                }
                try
                {
                    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errorString += ex.Message + ";" + ex.InnerException;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //Exception were catched here...
        {

        }
        return errorString;            
    }
```

> Exception:

```
"System.IO.IOException" wurde aufgefangen.
  HResult=-2146232800
  Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
       at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpPooledStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.IO.Stream.Close()
       at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.ForceCleanup()
       at System.Net.ConnectionPoolManager.CleanupConnectionPool(ServicePoint servicePoint, String groupName)
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Dispose()
       at Framework.MailTool.SimpleMailTool`2.<SendMail>d__19.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Administrator\Source\Repos\syp-project-api-server2\Framework\MailTool\SimpleMailTool.cs:line 159
  InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
       Source=System
       ErrorCode=10054
       NativeErrorCode=10054
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
            at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
       InnerException:
```

I'm confused ;-)
Plese help

Comment: Sounds like you aren't authenticated.

Comment: No the email were sent without any problems, no error in SMTP Server log, and the email lands in the recipients inbox ;-)

Comment: Add the stack trace.

Comment: There is only one line in the Stack Trace: Framework.dll!Framework.MailTool.SimpleMailTool<Settings>.SendMail(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mailMessage) Zeile 162 C#

Comment: Try to remove "using (var ...)".  Write an explicit "smtpclient.Close()" after SendMailAsync.  It seems your "using" is closing the connection before the async operation has finished his work.

Comment: There exist no Close Methode for SmtpClient, and calling Dispose throw the same exception.
I have also tried to send the mail synchoniously, but the same exception was thrown

Comment: The MSDN example doesn't use a using which will call dispose on the object. What happens if you get rid of the using? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If I don't dispose SmtpClient there is no exception, but I dont know what happens with the allocated ressources.